# E[X*Y] for the sum and difference of a dice rolling and independence

Tags: probability

I have a question with respect to a probability question where my intuition is kind of hindering the definition of independence and correlation here. It goes as follows:

> A die is rolled twice. Let X denote the sum of the two numbers that turn up, and Y the difference of the numbers (specifically, the number on the first roll minus the number on the second). Show that E(XY ) = E(X)E(Y). Are X and Y independent?

I understand why E[XY] = E[X]E[Y] and this goes for random variables that are uncorrelated but yet my intuition tells me that having information about X provides some information about Y given that they are both an outcome of the first two tosses, if that makes sense. Although sometimes I did reason that there are cases where the sum can be large and the difference is small (i.e.: tossing 2 sixes but the difference being 0 but can one not infer any information from X for Y in this case ?)

Anyhow, if independence always implies uncorrelated random variables, does it go the other way around ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\Pr(X=2)\ne 0$ and $\Pr(Y=1)\ne 0$. But $\Pr(X=2\cap Y=1)=0$, so $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.